# Android Studio Debugger works but does not update layout

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

My debugger seems to be mostly working but after I reach the first breakpoint in the code it lets me step through the code but quits updating the app in the emulator. How do I fix this?

For example setting the text of a button (which works fine during normal running) does not cause the emulator to update in debugger mode

Comment: Well that is how the debugger works. You should resume execution or something to make it go through code again I guess.

Comment: Invoking `setText()` doesn't immediately cause the pixels on the screen to change. It saves the text to memory, so that the next time a _draw pass_ takes place, the `Button` will be able to update itself correctly. That draw pass isn't going to happen until you step out of the function you're in, and give control back to the framework, tho. In other words, _you're blocking the UI thread with your debugger_.